# es2015 preset issue with moment

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I'm using gulp-babel to transpile es6, below is the gulp task

```
gulp.task('uglify', [], function() {
    var notMinified = config.scripts.src;
    notMinified.push('!javascripts/*.min.js');
    // console.log(notMinified);
    return gulp.src(notMinified)
        .pipe(babel({
            "presets": ["es2015-without-strict"]
        }))
        .pipe(ngAnnotate())
        .pipe(gp_uglify().on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.scripts.dest));
});
```

I have tried presets `es2015`, `es2015-without-strict` etc.
While using `es2015` preset, there was an error in moment.js which says 'cannot set moment of undefined'. After googling the error I found `es2015` preset uses `use strict` at top level which converts `this` to `undefined`, hence the error in moment. So I used `es2015-without-strict` preset which says it transpiles without `use strict` but still no luck, having same error.

What could be possibly wrong here?

Comment: It sounds like you're creating a reference to a Moment method without properly binding it, so can you show the code where you use `moment`?

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's not actually about moment, it's about some of the 3rd party libraries. When I removed moment.js from gulp task, the error then came in tether.js